# C for loop: cond-expression expressed as an expression which is contextually convertible to bool?

Tags: c

How  C for loop having cond-expression expressed as an expression which is contextually convertible to bool work ?

Why loop stops when x is got assigned value Zero ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int decreaseVal(int i){
    
    
    printf("deccrease val:  %d  \n",i);
    
    return --i;
}
 
int main () {
   // for loop execution
   
   int x;
   for( int a = 2; x=decreaseVal(a);a--) {

      printf("value of a: %d  \n",a);
   }
 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question??

Comment: What is the problem you have with the code you show? What happens when you build the code? What happens when you run it? What *should* happen when you run the code? What is the actual and expected output?

Comment: And please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 2):

In C Language any non zero value is considered as logical `true`.

If the result of the `decreaseVal(a)` is non zero the condition is met. The assignment does not change it. It is simply an additional operation. It should be inside the parentheses.

```
for( int a = 2; (x=decreaseVal(a));a--) {
```

Another example of the assignment as a logical expression (string copy function):

```
char *mystrcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *wrk = dest;
    while((*wrk++ = *src++));
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: In this case the parentheses around the expression are useless. +1 anyway

Comment: @Jabberwocky I afraid that they are needed, otherwise the compiler will complain and in most dev settings (warnings as errors, high warning level) it will result in the failed compilation https://godbolt.org/z/ojEsjv13c

Comment: Fair enough....

Answer (score 2):

All of the basic types in C have a default behavior when treated like a boolean. For ints, a value of zero is false and anything else is true. For pointers, anything but NULL is true, and NULL is false. A 0.0 float is false and I think everything else (including inf and NaN) are true. When your function returns an int, the for loop treats that as a bool and whet it gets to zero, the condition is false and the loop ends.